# Caffe SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss Layer Multilabel classification c++

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a network that gets 2 input images, and these two images belong to more than one class out of 9 classes. All the examples I've seen - in Caffe docs - load input image directly from prototxt, however I feed in the information through my c++ code.

My input layer looks as follows

```
input: "data"
input_shape{dim:20 dim:6 dim:100 dim:100}

input: "class_label"
input_shape{dim:20 dim:9}
```

The loss layer looks as follows

```
layer {
  name: "classes"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "classes"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 9
    weight_filler {  type: "xavier" }
    bias_filler { type: "constant" }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "class_loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "classes"
  bottom: "class_label"
  top: "class_loss"
}
```

My assumption is that the input should be a stream looking like this 
[0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0], where 1 signifies that the images belong to the class and 0 means that it doesn't, is this true?

My second question is, what should I expect from the output of SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss layer (e.g SoftmaxWithLoss outputs probabilities)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are correct: the labels in your case should be a binary 9 vector.
2. The output of the loss layer is a scalar loss value. You should expect this value to decrease as you train your net. For prediction (test time) you should replace the sigmoid loss layer with a simple sigmoid layer. The output of the some sigmoid layer is a 9 vector with each entry representing probability of the presence of the respective class.
   The output layer in `deploy.prototxt` should look something like:

   ```
   layer {
     type: "Sigmoid"
     name: "class_prob"
     bottom: "classes"
     top: "class_prob"
   }
   ```

Comment: Great that's really helpful, can you post a sample of how the prototxt file look like in this case, then your answer will be more complete and I can mark it.

Comment: Is it possible to get a probability distribution for the `EuclideanLoss`-layer too? @Shai @Poka Yoke

Comment: @thigi what is the meaning of probability for a regressed value learned via Euclidean loss??

Comment: For classification you have got a probability distribution for all your classes. Lets say you have 9 classes you have got the probability for each class. For EuclideanLoss however, you do not have that you only get the probability for that one value. That is why I am asking. Have a look at this: [classification vs regression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658496/caffe-probability-distribution-for-regression-expanding-classification-softm). There this problem is described in more detail, if you didnt understand what I meant. @Shai